# Distribute date range durations across their respective days

Tags: sql-server

Given a dateset of *event* start and finish times, I want to calculate a elapsed durations. These durations must be summed per *equipment* (category) and distributed across the respective dates they occur on.

I have a dataset similar to the one displayed below.

[Example Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xG8Py.jpg)

This dataset is generated using the following SQL query.

```
    SELECT
    EquipmentDetailsDataModel.EquipmentDetails.Equipment
    ,StoppagesDataModel.StoppagesEvent.PlannedDownTime
    ,StoppagesDataModel.StoppagesEvent.PlannedUpTime

    FROM
    StoppagesDataModel.StoppagesEvent

    INNER JOIN EquipmentDetailsDataModel.EquipmentDetails
    ON StoppagesDataModel.StoppagesEvent.EquipmentKey = EquipmentDetailsDataModel.EquipmentDetails.EquipmentKey
    WHERE
    EquipmentDetailsDataModel.EquipmentDetails.Equipment IN ('22262','21617')
    AND StoppagesDataModel.StoppagesEvent.PlannedDownTime >= N'06/01/2016 00:00:00'
```

It is basically a listing of dates that an equipment will be down for maintenance (usually known as an event)

An output similar to below is what I’m seeking. There are events that can overlap, but an equipment can only ever be down for 24hrs per day.

```
Equipment   Date    Down Hrs
22262   01/06/2016  5.5
22262   02/06/2016  4.1
22262   03/06/2016  1.2
22262   04/06/2016  0
22262   05/06/2016  9.4
22262   06/06/2016  15
22262   07/06/2016  24
22262   08/06/2016  15
22262   09/06/2016  10.8
22262   10/06/2016  0.25
22262   … etc       … etc
21617   01/06/2016  3.0
21617   02/06/2016  5.2
21617   03/06/2016  1.7
21617   04/06/2016  0
21617   05/06/2016  9.4
21617   06/06/2016  15
21617   07/06/2016  23
21617   08/06/2016  0
21617   09/06/2016  16.8
21617   10/06/2016  0.25
21617   … etc       … etc
… etc   … etc       … etc
```

There is a system table built-in that I can use to return a continuous date range for the query.

```
SELECT
  SystemTableDataModel.ReportDate.[DATE]
FROM
  SystemTableDataModel.ReportDate
WHERE
  SystemTableDataModel.ReportDate.[DATE] >= N'05/01/2016 00:00:00'
  AND SystemTableDataModel.ReportDate.[DATE] < N'06/01/2016 00:00:00'
```

This gives a continuous date range to work with.

[Date range from system table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwyJk.jpg)

I'm struggling getting started on how to approach writing this query

Comment: can you provide schema to the tables, sample data in consumable format and also the corresponding expected result.

Comment: @Squirrel I'm not using the tables directly, just views derived from them

I've attached sample data and what the expected result should be.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/iys52dbv24uegob/Example.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: If you had a table with a date field (maybe temporary) with all the dates that you are interested in as records, you could then join that table to the downtime table if the there is any downtime on that date BUT if the start or end time is outside the day in date table, you must then set start time to 00:00 or end time to 00:00 on the next day - you would then have a query all with an actual date and a start and end time on that date.  Your 'temporary table' could eventually be generated as part of a WITH command, but if you started with your own table of dates, that is a good starting point

Answer (score 0):

```
--I think this is a start, make a table called MyDates with a column called ddate, then populate it with all the dates you are interested in 
--e.g. all of the dates in this year, you'll eventually be able to do that in SQL
--if you get the down and up time listed for each day, you will then be able to use GROUP functions to SUM it etc

SELECT
EquipmentDetailsDataModel.EquipmentDetails.Equipment
,MD.ddate
,CASE WHEN MD.ddate > StoppagesDataModel.StoppagesEvent.PlannedDownTime THEN MD.ddate ELSE StoppagesDataModel.StoppagesEvent.PlannedDownTime END DayDownTime
,CASE WHEN MD.ddate + 1 < StoppagesDataModel.StoppagesEvent.PlannedUpTime THEN MD.ddate + 1 ELSE StoppagesDataModel.StoppagesEvent.PlannedUpTime END DayUpTime

FROM
StoppagesDataModel.StoppagesEvent

INNER JOIN EquipmentDetailsDataModel.EquipmentDetails
ON StoppagesDataModel.StoppagesEvent.EquipmentKey = EquipmentDetailsDataModel.EquipmentDetails.EquipmentKey

JOIN MyDates MD ON StoppagesDataModel.StoppagesEvent.PlannedDownTime < MD.ddate + 1 AND  StoppagesDataModel.StoppagesEvent.PlannedUpTime > MD.ddate

WHERE
EquipmentDetailsDataModel.EquipmentDetails.Equipment IN ('22262','21617')
AND StoppagesDataModel.StoppagesEvent.PlannedDownTime >= N'06/01/2016 00:00:00'
```

--got to be honest though, it doesn't eliminate overlaps, but if you can get the hours up and down in a day, you are nearer

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! This has been a great starting point. 

I have some code working, now to find the cleanest version of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH BASE AS (
SELECT EquipmentDetailsDataModel.EquipmentDetails.Equipment, EquipmentDetailsDataModel.EquipmentDetails.EqpGroup, EquipmentDetailsDataModel.EquipmentDetails.Fleet, EquipmentDetailsDataModel.EquipmentDetails.Site, SystemTableDataModel.ReportDate.[DATE]
FROM EquipmentDetailsDataModel.EquipmentDetails
CROSS JOIN SystemTableDataModel.ReportDate
WHERE
EquipmentDetailsDataModel.EquipmentDetails.BranchKey IN (@Branch)
AND EquipmentDetailsDataModel.EquipmentDetails.SiteKey IN (@Site)
AND EquipmentDetailsDataModel.EquipmentDetails.EqpClassKey IN (@EqpClass)
AND EquipmentDetailsDataModel.EquipmentDetails.EqpGroupKey IN (@EqpGroup)
AND EquipmentDetailsDataModel.EquipmentDetails.FleetKey IN (@Fleet)
AND EquipmentDetailsDataModel.EquipmentDetails.EquipmentKey IN (@Equipment)
AND SystemTableDataModel.ReportDate.[DATE] >= @StartDate
AND SystemTableDataModel.ReportDate.[DATE] <  @EndDate)

SELECT 
BASE.Site
, BASE.EqpGroup
, BASE.fleet
, BASE.equipment
, BASE.[DATE]
, PlanHrs

FROM BASE

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT EqpGroup, Equipment, [DATE], sum(datediff(minute,DayDownTime,DayUpTime))/60.0 as PlanHrs
FROM
    (SELECT
      EquipmentDetailsDataModel.EquipmentDetails.Equipment
      ,EquipmentDetailsDataModel.EquipmentDetails.EqpGroup
      ,BASE.[DATE]
      ,CASE WHEN BASE.[DATE] > StoppagesDataModel.StoppagesEvent.PlannedDownTime THEN BASE.[DATE] ELSE StoppagesDataModel.StoppagesEvent.PlannedDownTime END DayDownTime
      ,CASE WHEN BASE.[DATE] + 1 < StoppagesDataModel.StoppagesEvent.PlannedUpTime THEN BASE.[DATE] + 1 ELSE StoppagesDataModel.StoppagesEvent.PlannedUpTime END DayUpTime
    FROM
    StoppagesDataModel.StoppagesEvent
    INNER JOIN EquipmentDetailsDataModel.EquipmentDetails
     ON StoppagesDataModel.StoppagesEvent.EquipmentKey = EquipmentDetailsDataModel.EquipmentDetails.EquipmentKey
    JOIN BASE ON StoppagesDataModel.StoppagesEvent.PlannedDownTime < BASE.[DATE] + 1 AND StoppagesDataModel.StoppagesEvent.PlannedUpTime > BASE.[DATE] AND BASE.Equipment = EquipmentDetailsDataModel.EquipmentDetails.Equipment
    WHERE
      EquipmentDetailsDataModel.EquipmentDetails.BranchKey IN (@Branch)
      AND EquipmentDetailsDataModel.EquipmentDetails.SiteKey IN (@Site)
      AND EquipmentDetailsDataModel.EquipmentDetails.EqpClassKey IN (@EqpClass)
      AND EquipmentDetailsDataModel.EquipmentDetails.EqpGroupKey IN (@EqpGroup)
      AND EquipmentDetailsDataModel.EquipmentDetails.FleetKey IN (@Fleet)
      AND EquipmentDetailsDataModel.EquipmentDetails.EquipmentKey IN (@Equipment)
      AND StoppagesDataModel.StoppagesEvent.PlannedDownTime >= @Now) T5
GROUP BY EqpGroup, Equipment, [DATE]) T6
ON (BASE.equipment=t6.equipment and BASE.[DATE] = t6.[DATE])

ORDER BY BASE.Equipment, BASE.[date]
```